# c# Select parent node, and show all childs in datagridview

Tags: c#, winforms, psql

I have a table called "Mechanic" which have recursive, the main id is "ID_Mechanic" and recursive is "ID_Chief".
I show all mechanics in `Datagridiew`.
And in `TreeView`, I show all parent and child mechanics.
And my question is, how can I create so that when I select parent node, all its child nodes show in `Datagridiew`?

Code how I create nodes -

```
public void FillTree(TreeNodeCollection tn, int? id)
    {
        NpgsqlCommand cmdtreeview = new NpgsqlCommand("select * from mechanic where id_chief is null", ncon);
        if (id != null)
        {
            cmdtreeview = new NpgsqlCommand("select * from mechanic where id_chief =@id_mechanic", ncon);
            cmdtreeview.Parameters.Add(new NpgsqlParameter("id_mechanic", id));
        }
        NpgsqlDataAdapter da = new NpgsqlDataAdapter(cmdtreeview);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        da.Fill(dt);
        foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
        {
            String newdatarow = dr["name"].ToString() + " " + dr["surname"].ToString();
            TreeNode node = new TreeNode(newdatarow);
            tn.Add(node);
            FillTree(node.Nodes, (int?)dr["id_mechanic"]);
        }
    }
```

Fill -

```
FillTree(treeViewMechanic.Nodes, null);
```

[Visual image of what i mean](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N4beK.png)

Ty!

P.S. Database is created in PostgreSQL.

EDIT:
Code what i got working but only shows first parents childs.

```
 DataSet ds = new DataSet();
 ds.Tables.Add(mechanicdt);
 ds.Relations.Add(new DataRelation("mch", mechanicdt.Columns[0], 
 mechanicdt.Columns[6], true));
 private void AfterSelect(object sender, TreeViewEventArgs e)
   {
        dataGridViewMechanic.DataSource = mechanicdt;
        dataGridViewMechanic.DataMember = "mch";        
   }
```

EDIT: LINQ

```
   DataTable newTable = mechanicdt.AsEnumerable()
             .Where(i => i.Field<String>("ID_Mechanic") == null)
             .OrderByDescending(i => i.Field<String>("Surname"))
             .CopyToDataTable();

        dataGridViewMechanic.DataSource = newTable;
        dataGridViewMechanic.DataMember = "mch";
```

Comment: Handle the click event on the tree view item and fill the item source for the data grid view there.

Comment: @ShivaniKatukota Okay, I got how can I show only childs, but it shows only first parent childs, how can I get so if I click other it shows its to?

Comment: Can you post code of what you’ve tried and how it’s not working?

Comment: @ShivaniKatukota Added edit in post with the code

Comment: That is because you are instantiating the data source with the same dataset. In the method AfterSelect, use linq to filter the dataset mechanicdt with only those members who have sender as the parent

Comment: @ShivaniKatukota Sry for bothering again, but i created something like this <code edited in post>, but i get error like  this `'Unable to cast object of type 'System.Int32' to type 'System.String'.'`

Comment: orderByDescending expects the name of the property with which you wish to sort, so it should be a string and not int

Comment: @ShivaniKatukota It seems that he does no like this line - `.Where(i => i.Field<String>("ID_Mechanic") == null)`.

Comment: @ShivaniKatukota now it just says `Child list for field mch cannot be created`

Comment: Ohh so ID_Machanic int property?? Then why do you convert it to string and expect it to be null?? Is it a nullable int?

Comment: @ShivaniKatukota OMG (facepalm)<me>, yea, id_mechanic is int, and id_chief is int, but the parents id_chief is null, but it always shows that you can not compile int to null. That is something like, parents value needs to be null.